# Fail to use imports in jupyter notebook in vscode

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, visual-studio-code, jupyter-notebook

I have a pretty straightforward code that run smoothly with Python 3.7:

```
import academic_data_settings as local_settings
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

def get_all_data():
    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(local_settings.ACADEMIC_DATA_SOURCE_PATH, "*.csv"))
    df_from_each_file = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files]
    concatenated_df = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
    return concatenated_df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    raw_data = get_all_data()
    print(raw_data)
```

However, it is pretty hard to visualize the data in the pandas dataframe.

In order to view the data, I found the following article on how to use Jupyter notebook directly from VSCode: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/python/data-science-with-python-in-visual-studio-code/

In order to be able to see the Python interactive window, I needed to turn the code into a jupyter cell:

```
#%%
import academic_data_settings as local_settings
import pandas as pd
import glob
import os

def get_all_data():
    all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(local_settings.ACADEMIC_DATA_SOURCE_PATH, "*.csv"))
    df_from_each_file = [pd.read_csv(f) for f in all_files]
    concatenated_df = pd.concat(df_from_each_file, ignore_index=True)
    return concatenated_df

if __name__ == "__main__":
    raw_data = get_all_data()
    print(raw_data)
```

As soon as I try to run or debug the cell, I get an exception at the first line:

```
import academic_data_settings as local_settings...
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'academic_data_settings'
```

I believe that the cell evaluation only send the code of the current cell. Is that correct?
Is there a way to get the import to work correctly?
I wouldn't like to end up writing Jupyter notebooks and then copy over the code to what will end up being the 'production' code.

Comment: where is your `academic_data_settings` package? is this locate with the main code when you rum vscode?

Comment: @Lamarus it is sitting next to the file I run

Answer (score 17):

I had a similar issue. I could import modules in IPython in the vscode terminal but not in the vscode interactive window (or jupyter notebook).

Changing the `.vscode/settings.json` file from

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "/MyPythonPath.../bin/python"
}
```

to

```
{
"python.pythonPath": "/MyPythonPath.../bin/python"
"jupyter.notebookFileRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
}
```

resolved it for me.

Comment: This should absolutely be marked the answer.  Thank you, you just saved me hours of searching.

Comment: This works. But note, python.pythonPathhas changed to python.defaultInterpreterPath

Answer (score 2):

Jaep. I'm a developer on this extension and I think I know what is happening here based on this comment:

> @Lamarus it is sitting next to the file I run

The VSCode python interactive features use a bit different relative loading path versus jupyter. In VSCode the relative path is relative to the folder / workspace that you have opened as opposed to jupyter where it is relative to the file. To work around this you can either change your path to academic_data_settings to be relative to the opened folder, or you can set the Notebook File Root in the setting to point to the location that you want for this workspace to be the working root. We have a bug to support using the current file location for the notebook file root here if you want to upvote that.

https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-python/issues/4441